# .pop() doesn't get executed for a deque object

Tags: python, list, collections, coding-style, deque

I have write a code to execute multiple command. I cannot find the reason, when i input pop, and print the deque object, the last element is not removed, thank you for help!

```
from collections import deque
N=int(input())
s=deque()
for i in range(N):
    inp=input().split()
    if len(inp)==1:
        comand =inp[0]
    else :
        comand=inp[0]
        element=inp[1]
    
        if comand=='append':
            s.append(element)
        elif comand=='appendleft':
            s.appendleft(element)
        elif comand=='pop':
            s.pop()
        else:
            s.popleft()

for i in s:
    print(i)
```

Comment: Can you provide a sequence of commands that reproduces the behavior you claim to see? `pop` works fine for me.

Comment: 2
 append 50
 pop
deque(['50'])

Comment: Right, I forgot I tested with `pop 2`, thinking a command had to have a dummy second element. But that leads to the problem: your indentation.

Answer (score 0):

The `if` statement that handles the execution is indented so that it's part of the `else` clause. None of your single-element commands would work; that `if` statement needs to be un-indented so that it always runs after `comand` and (maybe) `element` are defined.

```
for i in range(N):
    inp = input().split()
    if len(inp) == 1:
        comand = inp[0]
    else :
        comand = inp[0]
        element = inp[1]
    
    if comand == 'append':
        s.append(element)
    elif comand == 'appendleft':
        s.appendleft(element)
    elif comand == 'pop':
        s.pop()
    elif comand == 'popleft':
        s.popleft()
    else:
        print(f"Unrecognized command {comand}")
```

Comment: thank you very much,!now I understand, it took me 10 miuntes to write the code, 30 minutes to understand my mistake, still have lot to learn! sorry I have no enough reputation to upvotae you